# Why do some words ending in -o take the -es plural?

Tags: word-usage

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/plurals-of-nouns), most words ending in -*o* take the regular -*s* plural, but some take the -*es* plural. For example, these take -*s*:

- photo / photos
- zero / zeros
- avocado / avocados

But these take -*es*:

- potato / potatoes
- tomato / tomatoes
- torpedo / torpedoes

Most sites suggest that there is no rhyme or reason and that English Language Learners simply need to memorize which take which (although some words like 'halo' admit both pluralizations).

Other sites suggest that -*o* words that take -*es* have something to do with life. For example, 'potato' has something to do with life. Is the explanation acceptable? If not, can anyone provide an alternate explanation?

Comment: Maybe she meant that some of them end in *-oes* and some in *-os*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself understood. I mean some end in -oes, and some in -os.

Comment: To keep Dan Quayle confused.